# Firebase: Get userdata obj and bring back the user profile without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, firebase

It's been 2 days that I'm trying to achieve this but I need to refresh the page if I want the user profile from the DB. There is any way to do it **without** page refresh? I need to use some sort of jquery ajax to achieve it? Is it possible?

Here is my 2 method, they're working but they need a page refresh before they bring back my user profile.

```
 function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8000.firebaseio.com/users/public/');
    fb.child(authData.uid).on('value', function(data) {
      var myData = data.val();
      var dateString = myData.date.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
      $('.profile').append('<li>Username: ' + myData.username + '</li>');
      $('.profile').append('<li>Joined: ' + dateString + '</li>');
    });
    var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8000.firebaseio.com/users/private/');
    fb.child(authData.uid).on('value', function(data) {
      var myData = data.val();
      $('.profile').append('<li>Email: ' + myData.email + '</li>');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Profile: No data, no one is logged in');
  }
}
fb.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

or

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8000.firebaseio.com/');
var getAuth = fb.getAuth(); 
function getProfile(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8000.firebaseio.com/users/public/');
    fb.child(authData.uid).on('value', function(data) {
      var myData = data.val();
      var dateString = myData.date.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
      $('.profile').append('<li>Username: ' + myData.username + '</li>');
      $('.profile').append('<li>Joined: ' + dateString + '</li>');
    });
    var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8000.firebaseio.com/users/private/');
    fb.child(authData.uid).on('value', function(data) {
      var myData = data.val();
      $('.profile').append('<li>Email: ' + myData.email + '</li>');
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Profile: No data, no one is logged in');
  }
}
getProfile(getAuth);
```

db rules:

```
{
  "rules": 
  {
    "users": 
    {
      "public": 
      { 
        // allow me to list users by name
        ".read": true ,
        ".write": true
      }, 
      "private": 
      {
        "$uid": 
        {
          // only readable by owner
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".write": true
        }
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the content of ```authData``` on first load?   null or auth-object?       add a ```console.log(authData);``` at the beginning of each function.

Comment: you're right the object was undefined when was first called & after a refresh was executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `onAuth` and `getAuth` return `null` when not authenticated.     Fix your login/function call sequence.